# How can I check if the line that i read from a .c file contains #include<something>?

Tags: c

I got an issue working on a task. 
I am making different exercises in C (I can't include any c++ libraries).

I should read from a .c file and output everything in a .o file solving as well this specification.

"A line that begins with #include “filename.h” should be replaced with
the entire contents of the file called filename.h."

```
void writefile(int size, int *data, *file_path) {

    char outputFile[30];
    if (strcmp(file_name, "string_functions.c") == 0) {
        outputFile = "CW1_test_files/string_functions.o";
    }
    else outputFile = "CW1_test_files/math_functions.o";
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(outputFile, "w");

    //In questo modo andiamo a verificare se e' opportuno ignorare o meno i commenti.
    int numberOfLines = 0;
    int numberOfComments = 0;

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open file %s", filename);
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        char *line[1000];
        char *include = "#include";
        char *define = "#define";
        char ch;
        // file is equals to fp1
        while ((ch = fget(file)) != EOF){
            if ((strcmp(line[i], " ") != 0) && (strcmp(line[i], "\n") != 0) && (strcmp(line[i], "\t") != 0)) numberOfLines++;
            if (strcmp(line[i], "/") = 0) && (strcmp(line[i + 1], "/") numberOfComments++; //check the comments
            else if ((strcmp(line[i], "/") != 0) && (strcmp(line[i], " ") != 0)) continue;


        }

        printf(strcat("Number of Comments in the file %s: %d", file_path, numberOfComments));
        printf(strcat("Number of non-empty lines in the file %s: %d", file_path, numberOfLines));



    }



    fclose(file);

    //svolgere qui il resto del programma
    //stampare il file,, gestire gli #incl
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {


    }
    writefile(size, data);
}
```

Comment: Simply use cpp for that task. However, the `.o` files are usually not meant for the result of that operation.

Comment: `char *line[1000];` should be `char line[1000];`.  What is `fget`? Why do you call `writefile(size, data);` recursively? `strcat("xxx",...)` is always wrong, etc. About everything in your code looks wrong/weird. I'm not sure if your code is salvageable.

Comment: @Ctx using `cpp` would defeat the purpose of exercise, don't you think? :)

Comment: It sounds like he's trying to write a C parser, @Ctx, or maybe even a compiler.  He still could run the source he's parsing through an external preprocessor, but I don't think that's what he's after.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ok, understood. However, this will be not an easy task to do "by foot". As far as I can see, the code will - even when it seems to be working - not easily cover all cases to do the replacement accurately. To do this right, a _real_ parser will be needed, and then I would suggest to use a lex/yacc (read: flex/bison) combination.

Comment: I agree, @Ctx.  And I'm inclined to suspect that this task is more than a little over the OP's head at his current skill level, even relying on lexical analysis and parser-building tools.  (And maybe *especially* relying on such tools.)

Comment: I can't use cpp... the first task is create many functions like this in pure C

Answer (score 1):

The C standard specifies that a directive line has this form.

```
<maybe spaces> # <maybe spaces> DIRECTIVE-NAME .....
```

Before to check for this, you also need to cut out the '\NEWLINE'.  In order for your processing to be conforming with C, so to be able to process any valid file.

So you also need to skip the spaces before and after the `#` in your code and remve `\\\n`.

Comment: This answer only addresses _one_ problem. IMO the OP's code is unsalvageable.

Comment: @Jabberwocky correct, but if he wants to do it correctly he must follow the specification from ISO 9899 and must begin with what I suggested him.  Otherwise he is on a path that is only partial.

Comment: Not necessarily, @alinsoar.  Whoever set the task, likely an instructor, determines its parameters.  It is relevant to observe that the standard supports a wider variety of syntax than the OP describes or seems to be trying to support, but you are not in a position to know whether the OP must support the full language syntax.  In any case, relevancy to the subject area notwithstanding, this does not seem to be responsive to the actual question.